# Cannot declare class because the name is already in use, even when using require_once

Tags: php

I am getting the "Cannot declare class X, because the name is already in use in" error, even though the class file is included using require_once -- which should prevent this issue.

Simplified version of what's happening:

- class X was previously declared
- file Y begins with: "require_once
- X.php" error thrown

If I comment out the require_once statement no error is thrown (and subsequent code has no problem running methods from class X, since it was previously declared). But I can't comment it out because it's part of a library that will be updated periodically.

What would make PHP not respect the require_once statement, and appear to treat it like require? Note, we're running PHP 7.1.32.

EDIT - More Details

I don't think there's a need for more details, but here they are anyway. The issue is with the PEAR library. The base PEAR class has already been declared. A script I'm working on includes the Console_Getopt class (using require_once), which includes "require_once 'PEAR.php'" -- that's where the error is thrown. I don't want to modify Console/Getopt.php because it's an included library.

Yes, I realize autoloading is preferred. Most of my application uses autoloading already. But this is a library that I want to include without modification, and it has some explicit require_once statements.

What I really want to understand is why the require_once statement is not working as expected. In theory, if I'm using require_once to include files, I should never run into the "cannot declare class" error, because the whole point of require_once is to only include the file conditionally (if it's not yet been declared). Why isn't it doing that?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Was class X loaded the first time using the same `require_once` or same path and filename? Also, look into an autoloader as it loads based on class existence.

Comment: It's an oblique non-answer, but ... php autoloading is a great and modern strategy for avoiding this type of issue.

Comment: What's the code??

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-required-files.php  try to list out the file which are required even check is really thier or not